# No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying out an example from w3schools. I did pip install matplotlib, but it says no module named 'matplotlib'. I uninstalled and installed it again multiplte times using different methods. This also happens sometimes with other modules. Here is where I got the [code](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ml_linear_regression.asp)

```
x = [5,7,8,7,2,17,2,9,4,11,12,9,6]
y = [99,86,87,88,111,86,103,87,94,78,77,85,86]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Include your "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" line; and, really do double-check spelling (including capitalisation) of the name of the imported module. Failing that, there's lots of install-issues you should check (did pip intall work on the python install you expect, or are there both 32-bit and 64-bit versions installed?

Also, let us know your environment - which Operating System, what version of Python.

Comment: what are the outputs of `which pip` and `which python`

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing `pip install matplotlib`, try installing with `python -m pip install matplotlib`. This way you ensure it installs for the same python version as your `python` command is bound to.

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't work. I still has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
python3 -m pip install matplotlib --user

pip3 install matplotlib
```

Comment: Okay, please tell us which IDE/text editor you are running it, and which operating system you have